# How get filename from path php?

Tags: php, arrays, path

I have array with paths:

```
array (size=27692)
  0 => string './users/58/576709/16376/16376.mp4'
  (length=34)
  1 => string './users/58/578974/45475/45475.mp4'
  (length=34)
  //...
```

How i can get for example `16376.mp4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "./users/58/576709/16376/16376.mp4";
    echo basename($str);

?>
```

Output:

```
16376.mp4
```

And if you have a Array, as an example:

```
<?php

    $arr = array("./users/58/576709/16376/16376.mp4", "./users/58/578974/45475/45475.mp4");

    foreach($arr as $v)
        echo basename($v) . "<br />";

?>
```

Output:

```
16376.mp4
45475.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str = "./users/58/576709/16376/16376.mp4";
echo end(explode('/', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = '/www/public_html/index.html';
$filename = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
```

Could also work so for array.

```
foreach($filepaths as $path){
    $filename[] = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
}
```

This would give you a new array containing only the filename

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following code:

```
$array = array(
    0 => '/users/58/576709/16376/16376.mp4',
    1 => '/users/58/576709/16376/16377.mp4'
);
echo $array[1];
$array = explode('/', $array[1]);
echo $array[sizeof($array) - 1];
```

Last line would print the filename